# How do I put and replace a file using in a client machine in a Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, sqlite

I'm trying to make a Silverlight app which has a local sqlite file to search some data when the app gets offline. I found the following library, http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/ and it seems pretty nice.

So, what I want to know is, what is a good approach to have and place a file which might be replaced by automatically when the data in a server gets updated at some points?

I've tried to put a file into a folder under the app, but I couldn't access to the file by using csSQLite.sqlite3_open (This method is from the library above). Sorry, I'm pretty new to Silverlight, so my question might be very odd.

Thanks in advance,
yokyo

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this library has been specifially coded for Silverlight.  Despite being a pure C# implementation its still likely to assume the full .NET API is available.  This is not true in Silverlight.

Specifically Silverlight cannot ordinarily access the local file system.   The SQLLite code would need to be modified to understand Silverlight's IsolatedStorage.  It would also have to limit its file operations to those that are supported by the streams available Isolated Storage.

The creation of a DB-esq. data source in Silverlight is typically done by create Classes the represent records and collections of records, using LINQ to query them and Xml serialisation into Isolated storage to persist them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, to use a sqlite file, I should save the file to an isolated storage, right? Seems I need to understand Isolated storage things whatever I do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacked version of the SQLite code to work with Silverlight, you can use it for some ideas on what to do: http://www.itwriting.com/blog/1695-proof-of-concept-c-sqlite-running-in-silverlight.html